# How to run a python script as a background process that takes different parameters from the command prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, background-process

I want to run a python program that runs in the background. It takes a folder directory and  size as parameters and and compresses the files in the folder which are greater than the provided size. Also it will show description of the program that is in `helpInfo()` method if given the parameter

> -h

. [I have written the program normally here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XXmDbfpJ3c/)

Now how to run this program as a background process with `path` and `size` info given as parameters and will show help information if given parameter `-h`

Comment: you can use the `argparse` library to parse arguments passed in by the command line https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

Comment: Thanks. I did not know of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [documentation of argparse](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/argparse.html)

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("echo")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then using `python3 prog.py --help`